# How can I define a method with two Generic types and two type constraints?

Tags: c#, generics

My Method define is

```
public ActionResult _Create3<T>() where T:IMyClass, new()
```

but I want define tow generic type

```
public ActionResult _Create3<T, G>(G content) where T:IMyClass, new()
```

Type G must also use interface ImyClass but I Dont know define in where tow type !!!

for example if may be write :

```
public ActionResult _Create3<T, G>(G content) where {T:IMyClass, G:IMyClass}, new()
```

but get error.

thanks for answer

Comment: A simple search of MSDN found me this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define multiple `where` constraints on multiple generic types like:

```
public ActionResult _Create3<T, G>(G content) where T:IMyClass, new()
                                              where G:IMyClass, new()
```

Answer (score 7):

Add another `where` [constraint for that generic type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

```
public ActionResult _Create3<T, G>(G content) 
  where T : IMyClass, new()
  where G : IMyClass, new()
```